# Deleting Bullet Paragraph in Word using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, selection, bullet

I have the following text within a word document:

```
Total Amount Owed: <<Payment>>
Dates Mowed:
•   2/6/2019
•   2/14/2019
•   <<Mowing1>>
```

How do I complelely remove the text and bullet point for the line containing the string `<<Mowing1>>` using VBA?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try

```
Sub test()
Dim Pg As Paragraph,PgTxt as String

    For Each Pg In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Not Pg.Range.ListFormat.List Is Nothing Then  'Process only bulleted list
        PgTxt = Pg.Range.Text
            If InStr(1, PgTxt, "<<Mowing1>>") > 0 Then
            Pg.Range.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```